# RewriteRule help

Tags: php, security, apache, .htaccess

I have successfully setup htaccess to do this:

```
   domain.com/ad.php?ad_id=bmw_m3_2498224
```

INTO:

```
   domain.com/ads/bmw_m3_2498224
```

However, I have a link on the page which makes the page submit to itself...
The link saves the ad inside a cookie:

```
   domain.com/ad.php?ad_id=bmw_m3_2498224&save=1 // Note the 'save' variable
```

I need to make this work on the rewritten rule also, so this link:

```
  domain.com/ads/bmw_m3_2498224/save
```

will save the cookie...

I have this so far which DOES NOT work for the save part:

```
  RewriteRule ^annons/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ ad.php?ad_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

How can I include another rule to accomplish what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to add this line above what you currently have:

`RewriteRule ^annons/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/save$ ad.php?ad_id=$1&save=1 [NC,L]`
`RewriteRule ^annons/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ ad.php?ad_id=$1 [NC,L]`

This should get triggered before the general rule is and work just the same.

Comment: Yes, the way it's ordered - if the /save isn't set then it will go on to the next rule which is the one you provided earlier. What you might want to try is this:

`RewriteRule ^annons/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ ad.php?ad_id=$1&$2=1 [NC,L]`

Which will capture not only "save" but other things like "edit" or "delete" if those are functions your program understands.